# return value of selected value of v-for radio group

Tags: vuejs3

I have a radio group for a form created with v-for. I need to return the value of the selected button in a function. Here's what I've tried:

Use the v-model value. The issue is it returns the value of the button previously checked. This is due to the function using the current form value before it updates. I tried to figure out how to delay it or call the function after click with no luck, then was reminded of refs.

So I added the ref not realizing it applies the same ref to all inputs. Which of course it does, but this returns an array.

How do I choose the selected button? Is there a way to apply the ref only to the selected button?

```
<div v-for="mealService in mealServices" :key="mealService.id">
    <input  @click="setActiveMealService" type="radio" name="meal_type" 
            :id="mealService.meal_type_id"          
            :value="mealService.meal_type_id" 
            v-model="form.meal_type_id"/>
                                
    <label  :for="mealService.meal_type_id">{{ mealService.meal_type.name }}</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vue function event like this

```
 setActiveMealService(event){
   console.log(event.target.value);
   let meal_type_id = event.target.value;
}
```